Using Powershell to turn DNS Zone files into CSV
I'm using PowerShell to connect to and pull in several DNS configurations to run some checks. I have it connecting to the servers and pulling the the Zone Configuration file raw into a variable. It would be easiest for me to have the zone configuration converted to a CSV so I can query and compare different things throughout my script. I have the regex working to call out a single line, but I'm struggling to figure out how to do multiple lines while tying the groups of zones together. Here the relevant part of the script.
# What the output looks like when pulled from BIND:
$configurationText = @"
// DNS Zone configuration file

// Root server list
zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "root.hints";
};

zone "my.domain.com" IN {
        type primary;
        file "zones/zone.my.domain.com";
};

zone "my.domain.org" IN {
        type primary;
        file "zones/zone.my.domain.org";
};

"@

# Multiline Regex query
$regex = @"
(?<=zone ")(?<zone>.*?)(?=")
(?<=type )(?<type>.*?)(?=;)
(?<=file ")(?<file>.*?)(?=")
"@
# Test if this matches !
select-string -InputObject $configurationText -pattern $regex -allmatch | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches } | Out-GridView

I've also tried doing a find and replace to put it into csv format but I can't figure out how to remove the newline after the ';'
$DNSTemp = $configurationText -replace '// DNS Zone configuration file','Zone,Type,File'
$DNSTemp = $DNSTemp -replace '// Root server list',""
$DNSTemp = $DNSTemp -replace '.*zone "',''
$DNSTemp = $DNSTemp -replace '.*type ',''
$DNSTemp = $DNSTemp -replace '.*file "',''
$DNSTemp = $DNSTemp -replace '" IN {',';'
$DNSTemp = $DNSTemp -replace '};',''
$DNSTemp = $DNSTemp -replace '";',';'
# This is the replacement that doesn't work.
$DNSTemp = $DNSTemp -replace ';`n',','

This also wouldn't work as well if someone royally screws up the zone files.

This is not a complete solution, but hopefully it helps you move along with your problem.
You can use the full regex class in .Net to get more options. So this snippet will return all of the matching zones.
$regex = [regex]::new('zone \W(?<zone>[.\w]+)\W IN {\s+type (?<type>\w+);\s+file \W(?<file>\S+)\W;', [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Multiline -band [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnoreCase )
$matches = $regex.Matches($configurationText)

You can then loop through the named groups in $matches.
foreach ($zone in $matches.Groups) { $zone.Captures | Where-Object Name -eq zone | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value }


Thanks @logicaldiagram that worked for me. I was able to get the values grouped adding the following to your suggestion
$regex = [regex]::new('zone \W(?<domain>[.\w]+)\W IN {\s+type (?<type>\w+);\s+file \W(?<file>\S+)\W;', [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Multiline -band [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnoreCase )
$matches = $regex.Matches($configurationText)

$DNS1Zones = foreach ($Match in $matches) { 
                                            $Domain = $Match.Groups | Where-Object Name -eq domain | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value 
                                            $Type = $Match.Groups | Where-Object Name -eq type | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value 
                                            $File = $Match.Groups | Where-Object Name -eq File | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value
                                            [PSCustomObject]@{
                                                PSTypeName = "Zone"
                                                Domain = $Domain
                                                Type = $Type
                                                File = $File
                                                }                                       
                                           }


$DNS1Zones | Out-GridView

$DNS1Zones | Where-Object type -eq primary
$Zone1 = $DNS1Zones | Where-Object domain -eq my.domain.com

